# Есть ли библиотеки или другие модули под Unity, позволяющие написать компилятор?

Tags: c#, unity3d, компилятор

Мне требуется реализовать динамическую проверку кода на Unity, хотелось бы знать, существуют ли готовые библиотеки или придется писать компилятор с нуля?

Comment: что именно и как нужно проверять?

Comment: `...придется писать компилятор с нуля...` ->

Comment: @Bulson тот самый момент когда попытка - пытка. )))

Comment: Если вы пишите игру, не удивляйтесь, если кто-то умный потом сломает вам всю логику с помощью рефлексии в своем коде :)

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть 2 варианты.

---

1. Всё это взять в `string` и проверять весь код долго и счастливо, при том что у вас нет корневой доступ к коде, то есть ваша проверка будет работать медленнее, чем в обычных компиляторах.
2. Добавить этот код к своему и с помощью оператора `try` и `catch` ловить все ошибки.

Второй вариант выглядит примерно так.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UCompile;

public class CompileClassExample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Compile(string input)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            CSScriptEngine engine = new CSScriptEngine();
            engine.AddUsings("using UnityEngine;");

            IScript result = engine.CompileCode(input);
            try
            {
                result.Execute();
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                Debug.Log(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**[`UCompile`](https://github.com/aeroson/mcs-ICodeCompiler)** и есть та самая библиотека.

Comment: Не совсем ясно, как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос "есть ли библиотеки?". Как эти библиотеки использовать - вопрос другой.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker `UComple` это и есть библиотека которую можно найти в `Assets Store`

Comment: Кроме незаметного using'а ничто об этом не говорит, я лично не заметил. Ассет бесплатный и есть на гитхабе, имхо лучше прикрепить ссылки или хотя бы явно указать на `UCompile`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker хорошо